# Running C++ Builder 2009 on Windows 11

Tags: .net, c++builder

Don't ask why, but I'm trying to install C++ Builder 2009 on a new Windows 11 machine. The installer says it needs to update to .NET version 2.0, then says the update failed and I should install it manually. I already have the latest version of .NET and 2.0 does not seem to be available.  Any ideas on how I can get around this problem?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/install/dotnet-35-windows#enable-the-net-framework-35-in-control-panel